# Incomplete results when calling a method from a .net library from multiple threads at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm working on a GUI that shows the state of certain tools in our factory. The states can be requested through a webservice which is integrated into a .dll file. When my GUI application is started, i want to request the states of all the tools at the same time. To do this, i create a thread for every tool and then call a method that should get the state of the tool. I get some correct responses, but about half of the threads don't provide a response at all and some return false values.

If i run the requests one after the other, everything works perfectly fine. But that takes too long.

```
def request_states(self, resource, i):
    # self.driver.GetToolState is a specific method defined in a dll
    # it accesses a webservice to request data
    result = self.driver.GetToolState(str(resource), str(self.site))
    self.statedata_dic[i] = [result, state]

    if result.Success:
        print(str(resource) + result.ToolState.Description)
    else:
        print(str(resource) + 'no state av')



state_threads = []

# create a thread for every resource
for i in range(len(self.resources)):

    s_t = threading.Thread(target=self.request_states, args=[self.resources[i], i])
    # start thread
    s_t.start()

    state_threads.append(s_t)

for s_t in state_threads:
    s_t.join()
```

self.resources is a list with 30 entries.
the error seems to be appearing when starting the threads.

what i get:
1Standby
2Standby
3Standby
4Disabled
5None
6Standby
7Standby
8Standby
9None
10Standby
11Standby
12None
13Standby
14Standby
15no state av
16Standby
17Standby
18Standby
19Standby

what i want / what i get when running the threads one after another (no "no state av", all 30 threads provide responses):

1Standby
2Disabled
3Standby
4Standby
5None
6None
7Standby
8Standby
9None
10Standby
11Standby
12Standby
13Standby
14Standby
15Standby
16Standby
17Standby
18Standby
19Standby
20Standby
21Standby
22Standby
23Standby
24Standby
25Standby
26Standby
27Standby
28Productive
29Standby
30Standby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most probably caused by Python's GIL. Although you expect that the threads will just parallelise your requests, in practice is something in between and is specific to Python.

According to [Python's wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), "The GIL can cause I/O-bound threads to be scheduled ahead of CPU-bound threads. And it prevents signals from being delivered."

If you still want to do it like this, you could add a retry with a backoff mechanism inside the thread:

```
import time

def request_states(self, resource, i):
    # self.driver.GetToolState is a specific method defined in a dll
    # it accesses a webservice to request data
    backoff = 3
    while backoff:
        result = self.driver.GetToolState(str(resource), str(self.site))

        if result.Success:
            backoff = 0
            self.statedata_dic[i] = [result, state]
            print(str(resource) + result.ToolState.Description)
            break
        else:
            print(str(resource) + 'no state av')
        backoff -= 1
        # increase time wait with every backoff decrement 
        # so that I increase the chances to receive a correct response
        time.sleep(0.1 * (5 - backoff))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that solved the problem of all the threads returning incorrect data! however, i still have the problem that some of the threads don't even get to that point, i start 30 threads and get only somewhere between 15 and 20 responses... i will try to implement something similar to this in the thread creation, maybe that will do it

Comment: You should make sure that driver.GetToolState is thread safe. Make sure that it does not lock some resources. Maybe you should also have a timeout and kill the thread if it takes too long and restart those that do not have responses.

Comment: Some nice article on Python threads and GIL: https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil